# htaccess ignore directory and subdirectories of existing folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following structure

```
- .htaccess
- cms
- other_cms
-- xyz
```

In the `.htaccess` I have a lot of rewrite rules which I want to ignore for `/other_cms`.

I added the following on top of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^other_cms/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^other_cms/test/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^other_cms(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]
    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^other_cms/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

My goal is that every subdirectory of `/other_cms` (no matter if it really exists or not) and `/other_cms` itself is ignored by this `.htaccess` file in the root.

I also tried to add a condition to every rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^other_cms(/.*|)$
```

When I open `/other_cms/test` it still calls all rules and the 404 of the `/cms` is applied.

I have added an .htaccess file to `/other_cms` including `RewriteEngine Off` but I suppose this is never read.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I have added an .htaccess file to `/other_cms` including `RewriteEngine Off` but I suppose this is never read." - This should have completely disabled mod_rewrite for this directory -  the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file should not even have been processed. Note that the value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable starts with a slash - you've got this right in the first condition, but not the second. How are requests being routed to your "root" cms?

Comment: updated the code so I use with RewriteEngine On and also removed the "/". I tried both with and without "/" and nothing works.

So my main CMS (root) `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` for routing but I also added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^other_cms(/.*|)$` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following on top in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^other_cms/(.+)$ /other_cms/index.html?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

and I removed the .htaccess file in the `other_cms/` folder.

This makes sure it uses the `index.html` file of my subfolder.